How to automatically update .csproj files when adding new C# files in Neovim?
Following this post, I'm planning to migrate from Visual Studio Professional 2019 to Neovim for C# .NET Framework development. One crucial Visual Studio feature I need to replicate is the automatic updating of .csproj files when adding new source files.
In Visual Studio, when you add a new .cs file, it automatically updates the project file by adding an entry like this in the appropriate ItemGroup section:
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="path\to\fileName.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

Is there a way to implement similar functionality in Neovim? I'm looking for solutions that could involve:

Existing plugins (preferably compatible with lazy.nvim)
Custom Lua/VimScript implementation
File watchers or other automation approaches

The ideal solution would:

Detect when a new .cs file is created
Automatically locate the corresponding .csproj file
Update the XML structure by adding the Compile element in the correct ItemGroup
Maintain proper relative paths

I think if no existing plugins provide this functionality then I have to write custom solutions in Lua or VimScript.
Does anyone have experience implementing this kind of .NET project file automation in vi/vim/nvim?

I highly suggest you also migrate to the SDK-style format for projects, as they scan directories and include C# source file automatically

@MindSwipe is that part of .NET Core? If yes, we are yet to migrate. We are, unfortunately, still using legacy proprietary .NET Framework.

Nope, you can use SDK-style projects with .NET Framework. Here is a list of supported frameworks for the TargetFramework element.

@MindSwipe How can I instruct Visual Studio to use the SDK-style format for projects? How can I convert the existing project?

Check the answers here, for porting existing Projects especially this one

@MindSwipe does the SDK-style format for projects scan the code base recursively? does it scan the nested folders as well?

@MindSwipe wow! this is impressive. It simplifies the .csproj file into just several lines. I am gonna propose this internally to see if we can use this instead. thanks.
